# How to execute batch commands before clearing git repository?

Tags: jenkins

My current Jenkins job has the flow:

1. Wipe out git repository and clone

[image]

[image]

2. Execute Windows batch commands in build

My requirement is to execute windows batch commands before Wiping out the repository. Is this possible in Jenkins? If not, is there a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Make images visible with a bang, e.g. `![][1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PreSCM plugin should suit your purpose.
Link: https://plugins.jenkins.io/preSCMbuildstep

You can run windows batch command and well as shell commands.

Let me know if you need any help.